# HTML5 data attribute is empty, but javascript does not agree with this situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make some functionality with JavaScript but JavaScript does not agree with logic.

In my console I have inspect the element that I try to manipulate and I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="address" autocomplete="off" data-lat="" data-lng="">
```

and then I like to check if the `data-lat` or the `data-lng` attributes are empty.

In my JavaScript file I have this code:

```
$addressField.on(
    'blur',
    function()
    {
        console.assert($addressField.attr('data-lat') != '',    'Address latitude it is not empty');

        if($addressField.val() == '')
        {
            $addressField.attr('data-lat', '').attr('data-lng', '').val('');
        }
        else if($addressField.attr('data-lat') == '' || $addressField.attr('data-lng') == '')
        {
            $addressField.attr('data-lat', '').attr('data-lng', '').val('');
        }
    }
)
```

When I load my page, I am getting the following message in my console:

```
Assertion failed: Address latitude it is not empty
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Or just JavaScript getting in sane ?

**UPDATE #1**

I am sorry, but I didn't made clear that I run this code on blur event of the `$addressField`. I have modify the code, in order to meed the  actual code.

**UPDATE #2**

Most of you have stack on the `console.assert`, but even If I don't use the `console.assert`, the `else if( .... )` statement is getting again to false, and the second block does not executed.

The `console.assert` used only to help me identify the problem.

Comment: Well, when you first load the page, the `data-lat` and `data-lng` are empty. Thus when you assert that `$addressField.attr('data-lat') != ''` you're actually saying: I assume that the `data-lat` attribute is not empty, but if it's empty, show me the message: `Address latitude it is not empty`.

Comment: I guess, `$addressField.attr('data-lat')` returns `undefined`. And `undefined` is not equal to ''. Check the value of `$addressField.attr('data-lat')`

Comment: When you're asserting something, if the expression is evaluated to `true`, then you successfully asserted that "thing", so no need to show the message, but if the expression evaluates to false, the assertion fails and thus the message is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `UPDATE #2`

@Praveen Jeganathan said already that your assertion fails, which means that `$addressField.attr('data-lat') != ''` is `false`. This means that the value of `$addressField.attr('data-lat')` **is equal (or can be evaluated) to ''**(i.e. empty), and thus the first **if** statement is **true**, and the first block gets executed:

```
if($addressField.val() == '') //this expression is true
{
    //this code is going to be executed
    $addressField.attr('data-lat', '').attr('data-lng', '').val('');
}
else if($addressField.attr('data-lat') == '' || $addressField.attr('data-lng') == '')
{
    //this block it's not going to be executed, because the first one
    //was, EVEN THOUGH the expression from this if statement
    //evaluates to TRUE
    $addressField.attr('data-lat', '').attr('data-lng', '').val('');
}
```

This is the same thing as writing:

```
var someVar = 5;
if(someVar === 5) { /* Do something here */}
else if(someVar === 5) {
    //How am I going to execute this code!?!
    //The first one will always get executed
    //If the first one will not get executed, I will never be executed too.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the comparison operators == and === mean different things. Best practice is to simply avoid == and use === in almost all cases.

Comment: I know ;) But the first type check for value equality and the second check for value and type equality. In my case both operators will return the same result, as the values are in both sides strings

Comment: That's not the reason why the assertion fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact behavior.

Since the value is empty `$addressField.attr('data-lat') != ''` is **`false`** and therefore the assert is getting executed.  This is right.

This is how the message will get logged in chrome, check this [**docs**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoleassertexpression_object)

*If the specified expression is false, the message is written to the console along with a stack trace.*

Comment: Without the check operators ? And later in the code that I have to make the check for empty values how to use it ? :?

Comment: the message is displayed when the expression evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Check my code, I juast updated. Note: I was not the one downvoted your answer :)

Comment: var something = 5
undefined
console.assert(something == 5, "some message")
undefined
console.assert(something != 5, "some message")
Assertion failed: some message VM300:2
undefined

Comment: I'll upvote back your answer when you correct it. The assertion gets executed when the expression evaluates to `false`.